# Can't run brew install wine

Tags: homebrew, wine

This is part of brew output

```
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/sane-backends/1.0.23 --localstatedir=

==> make

==> make install

Warning: Could not link sane-backends. Unlinking...

Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully

The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link sane-backends'

Possible conflicting files are:

Warning: Could not link sane-backends. Unlinking...

Error: File exists - /usr/local/share/man/man8
```

Can anybody tell me what is going on and how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a `/usr/local/share/man/man8` that is a regular file.  If so, delete that and try again.